# access class from other class codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, class, rackspace

I have this class that I made as a library in codeigniter

```
 class Openstack{


function __construct($params = array())
{


    //namespace OpenCloud;

    // note that we have to define these defaults BEFORE including the
    // connection class
    define('RAXSDK_OBJSTORE_NAME','cloudFiles');
    define('RAXSDK_OBJSTORE_REGION','ORD');
    require_once('lib/rackspace.php');

    // these hold our environment variable settings
    define('AUTHURL', 'https://identity.api.rackspacecloud.com/v2.0/');
    define('USERNAME', "#####");
    define('TENANT', "$$$$$");
    define('APIKEY', "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf");

    // establish our credentials
    $connection = new Rackspace(AUTHURL,
        array( 'username' => USERNAME,
               'tenantName' => TENANT,
               'apiKey' => APIKEY ));


    $ostore = $connection->ObjectStore();...
```

The problem is, when I call a function using:

```
 public function test_upload(){
    $this->load->library('opencloud/openstack');


    $this->openstack->upload_file("thisworks.pdf", "static/news/10_12.pdf");

}
```

I get an error saying the class Rackspace isn't found pointing to the line above where I have new Rackspace...

Within the rackspace.php there is a clas name called Rackspace

```
 class Rackspace extends OpenStack{ ...
```

I have no idea why it can't find it... I know it's loading the file, because I tried to echo something out in there and it showed up....

Any idea what's happening?

EDIT: At the top of the rackspace.php file there is a

```
 namespace OpenCloud;
```

I don't have that in my library file class Openstack I made... When I put it in there then I got an error "Non-existent class: Openstack"

Comment: I also tried to put it in a helper and got the same result...

Comment: So it looks like it has to do with the namespace...

Comment: You can use the library I made for rackspace https://github.com/meisam-mulla/php-opencloud-for-codeigniter